# R: new list with relationships

Tags: r, list

I've got the following list:

> Koppels
>       [[1]]
>       [1] 3634 3635

```
[[2]]   
[1] 5110 5200

[[3]]
[1] 5110 5951

[[4]]
[1] 5200 5951

[[5]] 
[1]  5535 26398

[[6]]
[1] 5699 7339
```

For each element of the list, it means that they are in relationship with eachother. So "3634" and "3635" are in relationship with eachother.

So the result of `[[2]]`,  `[[3]]` and `[[4]]` is that "5200", "5951" and "5110" are in relationship with eachother.

So now I want to get a NEW list, where I get an element like `5200 5951 5110` instead of three seperate elements like in the list above. But elements like `[[1]]`,  `[[5]]` and `[[6]]` has to be in the list too.

The list that I've used here is only a small part of the original list that I use. So the code has to work for larger lists too.

```
dput(Koppels)
list(c(3634, 3635), c(5110, 5200), c(5110, 5951), c(5200, 5951
), c(5535, 26398), c(5699, 7339), c(5912, 5913), c(7961, 8558
), c(10473, 10474), c(10475, 10476), c(23462, 23476), c(23750, 
23751), c(23750, 23752), c(23751, 23752), c(23753, 23755), c(24827, 
24828), c(26046, 26047), c(26048, 26049), c(26298, 26299))
```

Comment: Can you do us all a favor and share `dput(Koppels)` instead of just what gets printed in the console?

Comment: Are you trying to group pairs into joined networks, so you end up with a list of items that have no connections between them? Something in `igraph` package will do this easy.

Comment: Or, alternatively, are you trying to get groups all of whom are friends with each other (cliques)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use package igraph:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(do.call(rbind.data.frame, Koppels), directed=FALSE)
plot(g)
```

[image: resulting plot]

```
split(V(g)$name, clusters(g)$membership)
#$`1`
#[1] "3634" "3635"
#
#$`2`
#[1] "5110" "5200" "5951"
#
#$`3`
#[1] "5535"  "26398"
#...
```

Adjust as needed.

Comment: you might want to stick `directed=FALSE` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get lists of friends-of-friends, try this. It may be slow on large datasets - there are plenty of optimizations you could do.

```
Koppels <- list(c(3634, 3635), c(5110, 5200), c(5110, 5951), c(5200, 5951
), c(5535, 26398), c(5699, 7339), c(5912, 5913), c(7961, 8558
), c(10473, 10474), c(10475, 10476), c(23462, 23476), c(23750,
23751), c(23750, 23752), c(23751, 23752), c(23753, 23755), c(24827,
24828), c(26046, 26047), c(26048, 26049), c(26298, 26299))

nums <- unique(unlist(Koppels))

friends <- function (nums) unique(unlist(sapply(Koppels, function (x)
  if (any(nums %in% x)) return(x) else return(c()))))

friendlist <- Koppels

newfriends <- TRUE
while (newfriends) {
  newfriends <- FALSE
  for (i in seq_along(friendlist)) {
    l <- friendlist[[i]]
    fr <- friends(l)
    if (! all(fr %in% l)) newfriends <- TRUE
    friendlist[[i]] <- fr
  }
}
unique(friendlist)
```